# Why does JSON.NET on Xamarin.Android never finish parsing and how can I fix this?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, json.net

I'm building an app using Xamarin.Android and I've come across an issue where JSON.NET never finishes parsing. I've tried both the JsonConvert and JObject classes. Calling the parse methods never finishes. I added a breakpoint on the line that parses the string and one after it. The one after never hits.

What I've tried:

- Other JSON libraries: no succes
- Running the app on the device itself: no success
- Not using the shared mono runtime: no success
- Using an older version of JSON.NET: no success

I'm using the latest version of Xamarin.Android and JSON.NET that are available at this moment.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or why this doesn't work? JSON Deserialization is very important for this app.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It works for most of us. Could you please provide your code that you’re using and the json that you’re having trouble parsing.

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing any json I input. My code is literally just `JObject.Parse(input);` So I can't really get any more information about that.

Comment: The value of `input` would probably help...

Comment: The issue is that I have no idea on how to even start finding out what causes this @Saamer

Comment: alright, I'll remove some confidential data but the input should not matter because as I said, **any json I input is unable to parse**.

Comment: Alright, here's the json I'm parsing with data removed

Comment: Removed the link to the json, the issue was that it was an array and not an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, seems that I have figured it out. My input json was indeed the issue. I was trying to directly parse the input to an object, when the input json was an array with one single object in it. Parsing to a JArray worked fine right away.

Answering my own question just in case anyone hits the same issue and oversees the same thing :)

Turns out any input I tried had this same format of an array with one single object in it.

Comment: This is why it's importand to include everything required to reproduce the problem. Someone would have spotted the object vs array thing straight away. Remember that if you knew where the problem was, you wouldn't be here asking...

Comment: You can mark this answer which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Yeah StackOverflow told me I had to wait 3 days to do that but hey, done!